# Updating an existing user object in a loop

Tags: c#

Not sure  if I am going about this the right way but want to update certain properties of a user object contained in a users List based on whether it is contained in another list.

This is what I tried.

```
foreach (var v in usersAssessment)
{
    if (users.Select(t => t.Id).Contains(v.Id))
    {
        var user = users.Where(p => p.Id == v.Id).FirstOrDefault();
        switch (v.ModuleCode)
        {
            case "M01":
                user.M01 = v.ScoreObtained;
                break;
        }
        //this is where I am trying to update the user but to no avail
        users.Where(p => p.Id == v.Id).FirstOrDefault() = user;
    }
}
```

How can I update the property values?

Kind regards

Comment: You get a reference (not a copy) to the existing object from the `Where(...).FirstOrDefault()`, so updating the object will update what is in the list.

Comment: @crashmstr is correct, the user object will have the updated M01 property value.

Comment: As long as `user` is a class and is not a mutable struct :)

Comment: Cool, thanks allot, forgot the basics completely

Comment: Do you know what the type of `users` and `user` are?

Comment: Yes, they are both reference types...my bad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `users` is an `IEnumerable<>` or a reference type (any class), then you don't need to update it. You already did.

```
foreach (var v in usersAssessment)
{
    var user = users.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == v.Id);

    if(user != null)
    {
        switch (v.ModuleCode)
        {
            case "M01":
                // This WILL update the selected user, if users is a collection of reference types.
                user.M01 = v.ScoreObtained;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code, when you run this line:

`var user = users.Where(p => p.Id == v.Id).FirstOrDefault();`

you have obtained a mutable reference to the `user` object inside the list. Thus, when you execute

`user.M01 = v.ScoreObtained;`,

you have already updated the user and don't need to store it back into the list.

In fact, the line

`users.Where(p => p.Id == v.Id).FirstOrDefault() = user;`

is syntactically incorrect - the item to the left of the `=` must be a single, named variable reference - attempting to change the return value of a method like this does nothing, because methods don't work in reverse like that.